# securing Raspbian SD-Card

Tags: raspberry-pi, filesystems

I have a short Question related to Raspberrys but in applies in general to Linux systems.

Can I prevent someone from reading out the SD-Card of the Raspberry?
What do I mean: I can simply disable all login-posibilitys to prevent anyone from logging into the system. But if you unplug the SD-Card and mount it in another linux system, you still have full access to all files.

Is there any possibility besides glueing the SD-Card to the Pi?

I would be already greatfull for some keywords to google with ;)

Answer (score 0):

some Linux distributions (e.g. Ubuntu) support full disk encryption, which you can activate during setup.

Since you have an Raspberry PI, I assume that you have already installed raspbian. Therefore you can search for `raspbian home folder encryption` for example.

You can also set access rights so only the Pi user can open them.